# Prevent image and dynamic text overlap in a div element

Tags: html, css

I have a `back-button` image as div element within another.  The text in `#program_title` is dynamically changing and so is its width. I would like to prevent the overlap of the `back-button` image with the text, but have been unsuccessful.

So far -  I have tried floating the image left or right, styling both to `display: inline-block`, changing the margins, and using `<span>` instead of `<div>`.  If I change the position of `#program_title` to relative, this somehow interferes with centering the element.  I think there is something simple that I am missing.  Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

[image]

```
#map {
position:absolute;
left:25%;
top:0;
bottom:0;
width: 75%;
}


#program_title{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20202020;
  background: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.99);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  width: auto;
  top: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#go-back {
  content:url('./back-button.svg');
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 1%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  float: left;
  display:inline-block;
}

  <div id='map'>
    <div id='program_title'>
            <div id ='go-back'></div>
        <span>TITLE</span>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not keep the position absolute in `#go-back` as due to this particular attribute the back button has an absolute position irrespective of any other element on or around it. This would seem like the other elements are overlapping the back button(in your case the title), but actually if you scroll down the page(i.e. if your page is large enough to be scrolled down) you will notice that the position of the back button does not change. So change it to relative or remove the position attribute in style.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of code there that are NOT required! If the problem is with the image then a simple float would do the job. and it doesn't matter if the parent's div position is absolute or not! [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hgj7a45s/) I make a fiddle.

and all the CSS you need. and of course some of it is for style and you could erease it.

```
#map {
position:absolute;
left:25%;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#go-back {
  content:url('http://img.freepik.com/free-icon/back-button_318-69320.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg');
  float: left;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#program_title {
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `position:absolute;` from `#go-back` and instead use `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;`

```
#go-back {
  content:url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-and-universal-actions-icon-set/256/left_circle-128.png');
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display:inline-block; /* Or float:left */
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5weLg9ay/)